# Convert RGB8 byte[] to Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have raw pixel data coming from a camera in RGB8 format which I need to convert to a `Bitmap`. However, the `Bitmap PixelFormat` only seems to support RGB 16, 24, 32, and 48 formats.

I attempted to use `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed`, but the image appears discolored and inverted.

```
public static Bitmap CopyDataToBitmap(byte[] data)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(640, 480, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

    var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                         new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                         ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);

    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return bmp;
}
```

Is there any other way to convert this data type correctly?

Comment: Helpful articles: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719797(v=vs.85).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms969901.aspx)

Comment: Curious: What type/model of camera produces that format? Also: [this](http://www.theimagingsource.com/en_US/support/documentation/icimagingcontrol-activex/PixelformatRGB8.htm) source says it is a 8bit monochrome format.

Comment: Another quote from [this source](http://www.theimagingsource.com/en_US/support/documentation/icimagingcontrol-activex/PixelformatRGB8.htm): _RGB is bottom-up, the first line has index (lines-1_

Comment: Format8bppIndexed is correct format for your case. In addition, you need to make ColorPalette which maps pixel value 0 to RGB (0,0,0) ... 255 to RGB (255, 255, 255). See Image.Palette property.

Comment: @TaW It is a Vista Ey2 iris scanner.

Comment: @AlexFarber I am not sure I follow. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Can you post a link to one or two example image files? And: Are they monochrome or colored?

Comment: @Taw monochrome. Grayscale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a linear 8-bit grayscale palette in your image.

```
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

var pal = bmp.Palette;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) pal.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
bmp.Palette = pal;

return bmp;
```

You will still need to invert the scan lines, maybe like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
     Marshal.Copy(data, y * bmp.Width, 
             bmpData.Scan0 + ((bmp.Height - 1 - y) * bmpData.Stride), bmpData.Stride);
```

Comment: @Barry: please note the 1-off correction in the loop condition!