# C# convert an object to an image

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert an object to an image.

I grab the object from a usb3 camera using the following:

```
object RawData = axActiveUSB1.GetImageWindow(0,0,608,608);
```

This returns a Variant (SAFEARRAY)

After reviewing further, RawData = {byte[1824, 608]}.  The image is 608 x 608 so I'm guessing 1824 is 3 times the size due to the RGB component of the image.
The camera's pixel format is BayerRGB8 and according to the API I am using the data type is represented in Bytes:

Camera Pixel Format | Output Format | Data type | Dimensions
             Bayer8 | 24-bit RGB    | Byte      | 0 to SizeX * 3 - 1, 0 to Lines - 1

I can convert it to a bytes array using this code found at [Convert any object to a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865104/convert-any-object-to-a-byte)

```
private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();

        }
```

From here, I then do: (all of this code also found or derived from info on stack)

```
// convert object to bytes
byte[] imgasbytes = ObjectToByteArray(RawData);
// create a bitmap and put data in it to go into the picturebox
var bitmap = new Bitmap(608, 608, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
var bitmap_data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

Marshal.Copy(imgasbytes, 0, bitmap_data.Scan0, imgasbytes.Length );
bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmap_data);
var result = bitmap as Image; // this line not even really necessary
PictureBox.Image = result;
```

The code works, but I should see this:
[image]

But I see this:
[image]

I've done this in Python and had similar issues which I was able to resolve, but I'm not as strong in c# and am unable to progress from here.  I need to rotate my image 90 degrees, but also I think that my issue relates to incorrectly converting the array.  I think that I need to convert my object (SAFEARRAY) to a multidimensional array so that the RGB sits on top of one another.  I have looked at many examples on how to do this, but I do not understand how to go about it.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated on what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT**
I'm looking at this -> [Convert RGB8 byte[] to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161441/convert-rgb8-byte-to-bitmap)

which may be related to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue was exactly as I described.
In the end, the main issue was that the array needed to be rotated.
I found a solution here ->
[Rotate M*N Matrix (90 degrees)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034805/rotate-mn-matrix-90-degrees)

When I rotated the image, It resolved the picture issue that I was seeing above.  While my image is inverted now, I understand the issue and as a result, am not seeing the problem any more.

Here is the code in case anyone runs into the same issue

```
        byte[,] newImageAsBytes = new byte[ImageAsBytes.GetLength(1), ImageAsBytes.GetLength(0)];
        int newColumn, newRow = 0;
        for (int oldColumn = ImageAsBytes.GetLength(1) - 1; oldColumn >= 0; oldColumn--)
        {
            newColumn = 0;
            for (int oldRow = 0; oldRow < ImageAsBytes.GetLength(0); oldRow++)
            {
                newImageAsBytes[newRow, newColumn] = ImageAsBytes[oldRow, oldColumn];
                newColumn++;
            }
            newRow++;
        }
        byte[] b = ObjectToByteArray(newImageAsBytes);
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(608, 608, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb); // 608 is my image size and I am working with a camera that uses BayerRGB8
        var bitmap_data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        Marshal.Copy(b, 0, bitmap_data.Scan0, b.Length);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmap_data);
        var result = bitmap as Image; // this line not even really necessary
        PictureBox.Image = result;
```